# Is there any way to move individual entity from one server to another in Master data services?

Tags: master-data-services, master-data-management

I have master data model with some entity and it is deployed on production server.
Now i have created 2 more new entity in development server and wanted to move only these two entity.
If anyone has any idea please share with me.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Web-app(easiest): On your Dev server, go to System Administration. Click on Deployment and create a package. You then deploy this package by going on the production server, follow the same steps, but choose deploy instead of create under the 'deployment' button.
2. The alternative is to use the MDSModelDeploy.exe. You can find it on the server by going to the appropriate folder. Generally it's in this path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\Configuration.
   I recommend you use this method, as you have more control. You can choose to deploy with data, or without or clone your model. You can read more here ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/deploy-a-model-deployment-package-by-using-mdsmodeldeploy][1])

I can also recommend you consider the ModelPackageEditor when your model starts getting big. Then you have control over what you need to deploy, as in entities, views, business rules etc.

You need to have a deployment strategy in place, because if your development and production is not exactly the same, then you run into deployment errors. It normally happens when you create, for example business rules on the environment to which you are deploying and it is not on your dev environment. MDS uses copious amounts of id's and if the models are not in sync, then you run into problems.